# FPDI New line after ... characters

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf, fpdi

I'm creating an **FPDI** PDF. This is what I do now:

```
libraries_load('fpdi');

$pdf = new FPDI();  

$path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'xmed') . '/docs/verkocht_template.pdf';

$pdf->setSourceFile(realpath($path)); 
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');

$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 210);

$path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'xmed') . '/fonts/lato.php';

$pdf->AddFont('lato-light-webfont','','lato-light-webfont.php');
$pdf->SetFont('lato-light-webfont', '', 14);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);

$pdf->SetXY(47, 71);
$pdf->Write(0, $name);
```

I'm also placing some other variables on my PDF. This is the result now:

[image]

But as you can see the $name variable is to long... . I've tried this:

```
$naam = wordwrap($naam, 20);
```

But that gave me this result:

[image]

What would be the best solution to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [MultiCell()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm) instead of Write(). It allows you to define a width (1st parameter) on which the text will be wrapped automatically.

Comment: Isn't this gonne give me a border around the text?

Comment: Not if you pass 0 to the border parameter, which is the default value.